# Could someone help me understand how this component class works

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```tsx
import React, { Component, ComponentClass, ComponentType } from "react";

interface State {
  hasError: boolean;
}

const withErrorBoundary = <T extends Record<string, never>>(
  WrappedComponent: ComponentType<T>
): ComponentClass<T, State> =>
  class ErrorBoundary extends Component<T, State> {
    state: { hasError: boolean };

    constructor(props: T) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { hasError: false };
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error) {
      console.error(error);
      return { hasError: true };
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.hasError) {
        return <p>Something went wrong</p>;
      }
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };

export default withErrorBoundary;
```

So I know what this class component does. What I'm trying to understand is `<T extends Record<string, never>>(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<T>)`. I get it's a wrapper class but I can't wrap my head around it. Why is `<T extends>` defined before the class component? Any resources that can solidify my understanding would be appricted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is [a generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). Think of it like a variable for a type.

And it represents the props of the wrapped component so that the wrapper component can have the exact same props and pass them through.

So with this code:

```
const withErrorBoundary = <T extends Record<string, never>>(
  WrappedComponent: ComponentType<T>
): ComponentClass<T, State> =>
  class ErrorBoundary extends Component<T, State> {}
```

Let's go line by line.

---

```
const withErrorBoundary = <T extends Record<string, never>>(
```

This is a function named `withErrorBoundary` which declares the generic parameter `T`. `T` is *constrained* by `Record<string, never>`. This means that `T` must be a subtype of the constraint. In other words, whatever `T` is must be assignable to the constraint.

---

```
  WrappedComponent: ComponentType<T>
```

`ComponentType` is any react component, and it accepts a generic type for its' props. For example `ComponentType<{ a: number }>` would be used like `<MyComponent a={123} />`

So this function accepts a single argument of type `ComponentType<T>`. This is where `T` infers its type. Whatever the type of the props of the component passed as `WrappedComponent` is assigned to the type `T`, because `T` appears in the spot where `ComponentType` expect the props type to be declared.

---

```
): ComponentClass<T, State> =>
```

The function returns a class based react component with props `T` (the props that `WrappedComponent` would accept) and a state type of `State` (which is an interface you've declared elsewhere)

---

```
  class ErrorBoundary extends Component<T, State> {}
```

This line creates a class component that extends a react component that has props of type `T` and state of type `State`. This matches the return value of the function, and will be returned by the function.

---

Lastly, this type:

```
T extends Record<string, never>
```

is a little strange. A `Record` typed like that means an empty object (like `{}`). So this function may only take components that have no props. Which doesn't make much sense:

```
const MyComp = () => <>test</>
const TestComp = withErrorBoundary(MyComp) // fine

const MyCompA = ({a}: { a: number }) => <>{a}</>
const TestCompA = withErrorBoundary(MyCompA) // type error
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2&ssl=36&ssc=45&pln=32&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVgUZGRfgDYoDOT2hxtMAKgJ5hJwAvnABmUInABEUVBkkBuALAAoFcApIoI9AIDKMFDAE4VcOAAtmAUSjioALjgAjCBHqoSS5YJUq0pJngAd2AYcxs7ACEIAFcSABMUKB44AF44AB4uOCQADyMEpkQkfyh4jMCodQBzbDIAN00APiaAClM4AHUoFDB+ePYachhHQdJh3n4sppUASlHqcbpGFizsfUMkJrSZ5TM0FaKI6Gi4xOSc-PJ4orHONbgNo22TPbM4QM3HPEsmY4dnK53CgSEIvB19gEYFAYhhoK0wOIwExHFxZrgIe8mDF+FAEUimLMvO93mFgEwAHSfIxpXAWay2aCObT0JgCQTE94+VRvMzU4BoODVJAwAAimmAjXiTyQADFxCB-q1NHZHP90a8SZCSEw3EgKSr4YaoETMWYZDAYlBQT8Gaq4NCYuzOWZuZiZAlNK0NWa4MARHBWmTKdT9b91RjeVqLVbQRkwE1dEQReYanAgsN0+ISNUMgB6BMurm+mPWzLdXr9O6ZnAUuvBimIiDI4R5ppF7mu8E8-w6+AAWR4g1p3p2mSaRkC+d2vcCcC4SECw-SITC-1OCSSPFag8Gs18ylnA6H1AAgiOcChBN84ChHCQYiAnJohOjUtsMk1L4Jp34ofPFxgQZzxXUJwkZKAN3ObddzPWYgA)

Instead, I'm guessing this type was intended:

```
T extends Record<string, unknown>
```

This means that `T` is constrained by the type of an object with `string` keys and `unknown` typed values. This means the wrapped component can have *any props*.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2&ssl=7&ssc=61&pln=7&pc=28#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiVgUZGRfgDYoDOT2hxtMAKgJ5hJwAvnABmUInABEUVBkkBuALAAoFcApIoI9AIDKMFDAE4VcOAAtmAUSjioALjgAjCBHqoSS5YJUq0pJngAd2AYcxs7ACEIAFcSABMUKB44AF44AB4uOCQADyMEpkQkfyh4jMCodQBzbDiAaxIIIJIAPlaAClM4AHUoFDB+ePYachhHEdIx3n4s1pUASgnqKbpGFizsfUMkVrT55TM0daKI6Gi4xOSc-PJ4osnOTbhtoz2TQ7M4QJ3HPEsmGcHM5XO4UCQhF5ukcAjAoDEMNAOmBxGAmI4uAtcNCvkwYvwoMjUUwFl4vl8wsAmAA6H5GNK4CzWWzQRzaehMASCMlfHyqT5mOnANBwapIGAAEU0wAAbkh4q8kAAxcQgIEdTR2RxArEfckwkhMNxIamapFmqCknFmGQwGJQCH-ZlauBwmJcnlmPk4mQJTQdXXWuDAERwDqUml0k0AnXYgX6232iEZMCtXREcXmGpwIJjHPiEjVDIAelTnt5QcTDsyfQGQ0eeZw1ObEepKIgaOExda5b5Xqh-P8hvgAFkeCMGQH9plWkZAiWDkPAnAuEhAhP0iEwkCLgkkjwOmORgtfMol6Px9QAIKTnAoQR-OAoRwkGIgJyaIRY1J7DKtO+CAufiwiua4wCMN6bqE4QslAu5XAeR7XgsQA)